# Как заместить textView на webView в моем LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

У меня есть разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActionsMessages.MessageShow"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/theme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_of"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_attachment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

и мне нужно заместить этот textView на webView:

```
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/body"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

но у меня не получается, потому что пишет:

```
Placing a <WebView> in a parent element that uses a wrap_content size can lead to subtle bugs; use match_parent
```

я нашел такую [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709703/error-android-xmlplacing-a-webview-in-a-parent-element-that-uses-a-wrap-cont) там такая же почти проблема, но у меня не получилось сделать так же как и предлагают в ответе.

Не могу понять как решить проблему. Надеюсь на вашу помощь и полезные советы.

P.S. разметка может оказаться очень кривой и построенной неправильно, но я по-другому не знаю как ее сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое правило:

не помещать `WebView` в контейнеры, где хоть один из размеров указан как `wrap_content`. В случае с разметкой содержащей `ScrollView`, это скорее всего невыполнимо.

Избавьтесь от `ScrollView`, и может получится.

Comment: а как мне скроллить весь layout без скролвью?

Comment: придется выбрать, или скролить или вебвью.

Comment: спасибо что помогли, буду смотреть что более нужно, либо выкручиваться чтобы получить и то, и то